# postgresql alter role is not registering

Tags: postgresql

Importing via pgdump a database from another server to a 9.3.5 installation, I hit a number of errors in accessing postgreSQL's command line.

For example:

```
sudo su - postgres
psql -d template1
```

allows me to view users `\du` to `\list` databases, but if I state, according to documentation:

```
CREATE USER michaelrodent
```

or

```
CREATE ROLE donatoquack WITH LOGIN PASSWORD 'spltfrzspltrz'
```

`\du` only lists the default user or role.  However if I state from the bash prompt

```
sudo -u postgres createuser michaelrodent
```

`\du` then shows that role name.  Stupid me did not assign the role attribute to Superuser, thus when importing via psql, I'm getting errors like:

```
ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
ERROR:  must be owner of relation accbiadesivolumes
```

go back in as postgres user and I cannot:

```
alter role michaelrodent with superuser
```

...at a loss to understand why the postgresql command language is failing to register and how to use the shortcut syntax of sudo -u postgres [...] to alter role...

Comment: `..at a loss to understand ` is not an error message. BTW Did you add semicolons to the end of your command lines?

Comment: No, I did not. That effectively solves it.  silly crossing user syntassi that way...

Comment: Okay, I added that as an answer. For future use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you add a **semicolon** to the end of your command line, like:

```
alter role michaelrodent with superuser;
```

The reply/result should be:

```
krant=# alter role dba with replication;
ALTER ROLE
krant=#
```

Comment: I tried a LOT of different commands from all over the internet and finally yours worked. Thank you.

Comment: To alter a role in Postgres 10.1 the command requires a 'with'. To give the right to create a database, use the following:

     alter role <user> with CREATEDB